# Different date format on MAC and Windows in silverlight website

Tags: macos, silverlight, datetime

here I got an interesting problem..!

My website is created in silver-light. When I select a date from date-picker in Windows OS, it works fine with MM/DD/YYYY format. But when same date picker is used on Mac OS, it changes format to DD/MM/YYYY. and as I used parsing from string to date, it throws an exception of type "Bad_DateTime_Format".

What can be reason for this odd behavior ? Is this something related to Culture or MAC OS settings or something else ?

Comment: Do you have any [cultureinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.cultureinfo) set?

Comment: @ChrisW. No, I haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a number of odd attempts, I finally figure out solution or you can say a work around of this problem. What you have to do is to change date format on MAC in system preferences.

In my case, I wanted MM/DD/YYYY as as input format. So, i set MM/DD/YYYY format on my MAC machine and it is working as per expectations..!! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for this happening**

It is important to consider the users experience of visiting your website when coding things in a particular way.
In this instance you was looking to code the website with a US date format (MM/DD/YYYY) and received an error when handling a European style date format of DD/MM/YYYY

Naturally if you are in the UK, and you saw a date shown as MM/DD/YYYY, you could easily become confused if you saw 03/10/2018

Is this the March 10th or is it 03rd of October?

Therefore to prevent inconsistencies from website to website, web author to web author, the dates presentation format is taken from the operating system or browser so that the user always knows what date format is being used and is accustomed to.

**Solution to this error:**
Convert the time to a UNIX timestamp (seconds lapsed from: 00:00:00 on 01/01/1970)

example:

JS:
    var intCurrentUnixTimeStamp = Date.now();
    (date.now = Tue Feb 27 2018 12:15:21 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time))
    Output: 1519733721
    var intUnixTimeStamp = Date.parse("10-Mar-2018 08:18:48") / 1000;
    Output: 1520669928

You can always work with UNIX and even store it in a database and restore it back from unix to a legible time such as